# Distributed random variables

Tags: probability

Let $ξ_1, ξ_2, ...$ be independent identically distributed random variables and
N be an $N$-valued random variable independent of $ξ_i$’s. Show that if $ξ_1$ and N have finite expectation, then
$$E\sum_{i=1}^N (ξ_i)= E(N)E(ξ_1).$$

Comment: If you have the idea of how to start, it would be very good of you to share it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Begin with the Tower Property; also called the Law of Iterated Expectation.

$$\mathsf E\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \xi_i\right) ~=~ \mathsf E\left(\mathsf E\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\xi_i~\middle\vert~N\right)\right)$$

Comment: You are very kind. I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi_{i}\right)&=&E\left( E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}  \xi_{i} \ \vert \ N \right)\right) \\
   &=&E(N E\xi_{1}) \\
    &=& E(N)E(\xi_{1}).
\end{eqnarray*} . it's   ok?

Comment: Finally... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi_{i}\right)&=&E\left( E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}  \xi_{i} \ \vert \ N \right)\right) \\
   &=&E(N E\xi_{1}) \\
    &=& E(N)E(\xi_{1}).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Notar que
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}  \xi_{i} \ \vert \ N=n \right) &=&
E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \xi_{i} \right) \quad(\mbox{N independiente de los $\xi's$})\\
&=&E(\xi_{1})n
\end{eqnarray*}
Luego  $$E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}  \xi_{i} \ \vert \ N \right)=E(\xi_{1})N.$$
De esta forma, usando la ley de la esperanza total,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi_{i}\right)&=&E\left( E\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}  \xi_{i} \ \vert \ N \right)\right) \\
   &=&E(N E\xi_{1}) \\
    &=& E(N)E(\xi_{1}).
\end{eqnarray*}